# React-admin 4.1.0 - AutocompleteArrayInput and default value make search function not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-admin

I'm using react-admin library version 4.1.0 AutocompleteArrayInput with defaultValue prop, its search function is not work. When typing any value to search, AutocompleteArrayInput will clear all.

The search function will work normally if I clear all default values that have been supplied.

Have I make any mistakes here, or this is react-admin issue?

Here is my code block

```
const industries = useMemo(
  () =>
    record.disclosure_template_sector_industries.map(
      (item) => item.sector_industry.id
    ),
  [record]
);
<ReferenceArrayInput
   source="sector_industry_ids"
   reference="sector_industry"
   perPage={100}
>
      <AutocompleteArrayInput
        filterToQuery={(name) => ({ name })}
        validate={[required()]}
        defaultValue={industries}
      />
</ReferenceArrayInput>
```